# Creating multiple KML layers with as many Google Maps infoWindows

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've created a for-loop that draws multiple KML Layers on a Google Map. After that I'm trying to achieve adding a single infoWindow to each of the KML polylines. I can get infowindow appearing for each line, but all of them have the same content: the URL of the last KML file that I draw.

Here's the code:

```
function initmap(urls){
// Creating an option object for the map
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(61.130298, 24.009358);
var options = {
zoom: 7,
center: myLatlng,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
// Initializing the map
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), options);

if(urls != null) {

    var ctaLayer = new Array();
    var url = new Array();

    for(var i=0;i<urls.length;i++) {
        url[i] = urls[i];
        url[i] = url[i]+"?dummy="+(new Date()).getTime();

        ctaLayer[i] = new google.maps.KmlLayer(url[i], {suppressInfoWindows: true});
        ctaLayer[i].setMap(map);

        // Creating an InfoWindow object
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: url[i]});

        google.maps.event.addListener(ctaLayer[i], 'click', function(kmlEvent) {

            var clickPos = kmlEvent.latLng;
            var posX = new google.maps.LatLng(clickPos.lat(), clickPos.lng());

            infowindow.close();
            infowindow.setPosition(posX);
            infowindow.open(map);
        });
    }
}
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

If I do this, (add infowindows into an array), the InfoWindows wont even appear when I click on KML.

```
var infowindow = new Array();
infowindow[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: urls[i]
});

google.maps.event.addListener(ctaLayer[i], 'click', function(kmlEvent) {

var clickPos = kmlEvent.latLng;
var posX = new google.maps.LatLng(clickPos.lat(), clickPos.lng());

infowindow[i].close();
infowindow[i].setPosition(posX);
infowindow[i].open(map);
```

});

Comment: In addition to the infowindow question I should point out that you should not add the additional Date parameter to your KML url.  All it does is remove the caching capability of the KmlLayer infrastructure, which in turn means your maps will load slower, best case.  If your KML updates frequently, just set the expires header instead.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you only want a single infoWindow to appear at a time.  (Your click event has infoWindow.close() )  You need to remove the content: option from this line.

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: url[i]});
```

And put add it to your addListener function:

```
 var infoWindow = new google.map.InfoWindow();
    ....
 google.maps.event.addListener(ctaLayer[i], 'click', function(kmlEvent) {

            var clickPos = kmlEvent.latLng;
            var posX = new google.maps.LatLng(clickPos.lat(), clickPos.lng());

            infowindow.close();
            infowindow.setPosition(posX);
            infoWindow.setContent(url[i]);
            infowindow.open(map);
        });
```

Even better, create the infoWindow as a global for use by all your eventHandlers.